# Monitor many pic 16F877a microcontroller in single PC at a time

Tags: microcontroller, pic

I have about 300 boliers in my production unit. I am going to fix each with temperature and pressure sensors and each boliers will have one microcontroller fixed in them. Those read the sensor values. The sensor values read from 300 microcontroller fixed in 300 boliers must send their data to my personal computer and I want to monitor all the values in a single page. So I want to know how to connect them all together and read the data of temperature and pressure. And also what software , hardware should I use.

Comment: 1st decide on how much information is essential, useful, and how you need to view it, process it, manage it and write a spec

Comment: Why one PIC per boiler? Why that particular PIC? Over what distances? How much data and how often? Build it yourself, have it built, buy off-the-shelf? Hobby or professional? Any environmental issues (like EMI)?

Comment: CAN Bus can be a solution. But practically, it has limited num. of nodes (e.g. 120). So a multi-channel CAN network can be used. But distance is important here. Also note that the more nodes on the bus, the lower the allowed data rate.

Comment: This seems to be identical to your previous question.  Don't keep posting more of the same crappy question.  Fix the original instead. -1 for trying to get away with something and abusing the system.  Also, what's a "bolier"?  Do you mean "boiler", perhaps?

Comment: When I designed a SCADA system with similar numbers of channels and analog readings before the term SCADA was "invented" and PLC's did not exist. I successfully designed the system top-down then bottoms up with my specs. The result was a CRT on a 2 page result of all results with alarm  or out of tolerance conditions in Inverse video and or flashing for instant feedback. This is what I mean,  by a top level information (search OSI  model) functional spec. Then understand the OSI  model and with a budget write specs on cost and function of each layer. A PIC is only $1 but may not be best sol'n.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using a Programmable Logic Controller (PLC) when working in an industrial environment. This could be very expensive depending on where you source it from. Most PLCs have analog controller module expansion cards that can be used for sensors. Most PLCs also have Ethernet modules, which then comes with Windows drivers that can be accessed using ODBC datasources in Visual Basic or similar high level software development tools. You might have to verify whether the particular PLC could be expanded to have 300 analog channels.

Comment: If each boiler has a temperature and a pressure sensor he'd need 600 analogue channels. But that's not what the question is asking for.